# Java stream add result of method call to another collection

Tags: java, stream

I have an ArrayLIst (without diamond operator), which stores objects of type UserHelper. I would like to rewrite the Iterator code to stream, but I am not sure how to add the result of a method call to the collection. Here is my code:

```
    List<AdminDto> result = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList userHelperAL = getUsersToAdd(start, num, usernameFilter, fullnameFilter);

    for (Iterator userIt = userHelperAL.iterator(); userIt.hasNext();) {
        // get the user
        UserHelper userHelper = (UserHelper) userIt.next();

        // get the user's permissions
        AdminDto userPermissionDto = getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions(userHelper);
        result.add(userPermissionDto);
    }
```

The `getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions` method is a private method in `SomeService` class.

Here I try to rewrite the code above to stream:

```
    userHelperAL.stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj instanceof UserHelper)
        .map(obj -> (UserHelper) obj)
        .map(SomeService::getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> result));
```

The error I am getting here is: `The type SomeService does not define getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions(Object) that is applicable here.` It seems that it is trying to pass an object of type `Object` instead of `UserHelper`

Here is the `getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions` method:

```
private AdminDto getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions(UserHelper userHelper) {
    long consolePermissions = userHelper.getConsolePermissions();

    // Add the user's permissions to the map
    Map<String, Boolean> permissionMap = getUserAdminPermissionMap();
    int index = 0;

    for (String key : permissionMap.keySet()) {
        // the value is hidden for legacy purposes
        permissionMap.put(key, someVALUE);
        ++index;
    }

    // build the dto 
    AdminDto resultDto = getAdminUserManagementPermissions(permissionMap);

    return resultDto;
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Why *is* that `ArrayList` a raw type? Your method reference is wrong btw, it's not a static method so you need `this::`.

Comment: You need to show us `getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions` method declaration because that's where the error rises!

Comment: updated the question, added getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions method definition

Comment: `List<AdminDto> result =  userHelperAL.stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj instanceof UserHelper)
        .map(obj -> (UserHelper) obj)
        .map(SomeService::getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Naman The type SomeService does not define getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions(Object) that is applicable here. It tries to pass Object as param instead of mapped UserHelper above

Answer (score 0):

This is more explicit:

```
userHelperAL.stream()
        .filter(UserHelper.class::isInstance)
        .map(UserHelper.class::cast)
        .map(SomeService::getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> result));
```

what java version are you using as there's been a lot of minor changes to casting inference/erasure in the last few releases.

Comment: I am using Java 8. I think 221 release. I will check the cast in about 1 hour and I will let you know if it worked. For now I have created a method which takes (Object) param and then calls the method which takes (UserHelper) param, implicitly casting the object to UserHelper

Comment: @AndrewT why dont write something like:?
```java
userHelperAL.stream()
        .map(obj -> getNewAdminDtoByConsolePermissions((UserHelper) obj))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> result));
```

Comment: @MikhailPashkov no real reason, other than isInstance will also exclude nulls which one assumes is desired from the instanceOf check.

There are a lot of ways to do this.